# Pico-itx motherboard Powered With Battery

Tags: batteries, low-power, motherboard, portable

I want to built a portable pc system. I am interested in the [Pico511 pico-itx motherboard](http://www.axiomtek.com/Download/Spec/en-US/pico511.pdf).

My concern is how to run a system like this on battery.
It's using 12V and for the top configuration it needs 2.5A. So if I have a 10,000mAh (10Ah) battery @ 12V, it will only power it up for 4 hours? (let's pretend there is no display or anything for now..)

- Do I need a huge heavy battery? How laptops do this with 2x better cpu's?
- Do I need a special "magic" battery? Or to look at some low-power boards?
- And the last one, if I need to look at some more power-friendly boards, are there any good ones? (with kaby lake cpu's let's say)

To those who help me, may the force be with you!

-Christos Christou.

Comment: This kind of boards is not optimized for portable applications. Laptops, instead, are. That's why you see laptops, which last way longer, with smaller or similar battery capacities. By the way, you should not only consider the battery capacity (how many mAh, i.e. how much charge), but also the voltage. In other words, the energy (expressed in J or usually Wh). Given the voltage, I assume you're referring to a lead-acid (or 10 Ni-MH) battery. Li-Ion (and similar) are much lighter and have better performance, in terms of energy density (less volume/weight).

Comment: Hello, Yes of course I also count voltage (I mentioned it in the question), I knew that laptops are more efficient, that's why I asked if there are any low power boards, but without the sacrifice of the CPU. Thank you!

Comment: You are listing 2.5A as **continuous** load. Unless you're doing something like cryptomining, compute-heavy gaming or some other compute-heavy task, your board is unlikely to draw this continuously. If you were to do cryptomining on a laptop, its battery like would drop significantly.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you for your answer! So this board still have it's chances. Unfortunately I'll have to test it by myself for "normal-usage" battery drain.

Answer (score -1):

Your load requires 12 V at 2.5 A to power it.  To power it for 4 hours therefore takes 10 Ah, at 12 V of course.  Your math is therefore correct.  However, that does not mean you should get a "10 Ah" battery.  Depending on the exact battery chemistry, running a battery totally down can cause permanent damage.  This is true of typical "car" 12 V lead-acid batteries, for example.

Fortunately, 12 V car batteries start a higher than 10 Ah.  A 20 or 30 Ah car is a choice for running your device for 4 hours.  There are also "deep cycle" batteries intended to be drained closer to empty, but of course these usually cost more for the same capacity.

Your question about "huge" and "heavy" can't be answered since you haven't defined those terms.  We do engineering here, not hand waving.  Magic is clearly off topic, and so are product recommendations.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer. First of all the word magic was in quotes.. intentionally. Second, I didn't know that I needed to provide specific dimensions of huge and heavy. I mentioned clearly that I want to build a portable device. I think you can imagine which sizes of batteries can fit in a portable device and which not. And third.. I do know that my math are right. It's totally fine to say a board's name, I just wanted a suggestion of a better low-power board if any.